# how to open excel file from internet

Tags: flutter

I am trying to open a excel file from internet.
I am using [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) but it is not working

I am trying this

```
 Future<File> _fileFromUrl(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);

    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final file = File(p.join(documentDirectory.path, 'excel_file.xslx'));
    print(file.path);
    print(await file.exists());

    file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);

    return file;
  }

File excelFile = await _fileFromUrl(path);
OpenFile.open(excelFile.path);
```

Comment: please provide us with the exceptions thrown.

Comment: not exception is thrown. open_file is working fine but when i try to open that file it says file format is not supported